# What happens when reading from unreliable IO stream (e.g. Internet) using a while loop?

Tags: tcp, inputstream, iostream, networkstream

I have been told that when reading from any IO source, e.g. a file on hard drive or from an Internet URL, the program probably read from some kind of input stream object, which allow it to pull N bytes (or a line of text) every time until there is no bytes left.

When I look for some source code I will usually find something like:

```
fh = open('my_text_file.txt')
while True:
    line = fh.readline()
    print(line)
    if not line:
        break
fh.close()
```

or

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

These code usually use a while loop keep reading n-bytes or a line until there's nothing return from stream object. I can understand when reading from local IO source (e.g. hard drive) the file stream is usually quite reliable, such that there is always the next byte available on the stream until the file is finished.

My question is, what if the input stream is an unreliable source? e.g. the Internet. In such case, the while loop will just keep reading bytes or line from the stream until there is nothing return. But how does it know it is really the end of the file but not just because of network congestion when it reads nothing? Even most network today use reliable protocol e.g. TCP which will guarantee the file is intact at the end. But even with TCP there is no guarantee the parts of the file will arrive just in time to let the read() function read something to prevent the while loop from breaking before the end of file? I am just curious how does these input stream object really work in a very low level sense.

Answer (score 0):

They don't, they're high-level abstractions.

If a socket gets disconnected or a drive crashes while you're reading from it through a steam, the read will fail, either by returning a particular value or by throwing an exception.